# FCM integration in android, Why Firebase importing everything?

Tags: android, firebase, external, libraries, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have recently added FCM to my project and it's working fine. I have used

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
```

this line for the library since messaging service is only required. But when I have seen the external libraries dir there are many firebase classes which have no use in my app. Please see the image below.

[image: a busy cat]

Edited : Here is the whole dependency clause

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.3'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
```

}

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: show your build.gradle dependencies

Comment: Added the build.gradle dependencies.

Comment: Why do you import the entire play services lib?

Comment: @TimCastelijns do you think this is the problem? The extra libs are of the firebase.

Comment: No I don't but I was just curious since that lib is absolutely huge

Comment: @TimCastelijns Your guess worked for me. I just removed the entire play-services lib. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including more libraries than you need because you are using the general play-services library and not using the split libraries like play-services-drive or some other specific library.

By using play-services:9.0.2 you are saying you want to include all libraries in Google Play services including all the Firebase ones.

Removing the play-services:9.0.2 dependency and replacing it with a specific one like play-services-drive:9.0.2 (depending on what APIs you want to use) should fix your issue.

Comment: @thompson Yes that's what I did to have less number of libs. Thanks for your efforts :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe since you don't add the core lib dependency explicity. The messaging dependency downloads all of the Firebase one.

Try adding the core and messaging both to limit the things to messaging part

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.1'
```